# .Net Core docker container unable to connect to MySQL docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a mysql database hosted on a docker container. I am able to connect to the mysql database(hosted on a docker container) using dbeaver client application on my windows 10 machine. I am however not able to connect to it from my .Net core application deployed on another docker container. I get a `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.` error.

What could I be missing?

**Appsettings.json:**

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "InstaTranscribeDBConnection": "server=localhost;port=3306;database=wordpress;user=root;password=SomePassword;"
  },
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["server/InstaTranscribe.Server.csproj", "server/"]
COPY ["client/InstaTranscribe.Client.csproj", "client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "server/InstaTranscribe.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/server"
RUN dotnet build "InstaTranscribe.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "InstaTranscribe.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "InstaTranscribe.Server.dll"]
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

**entrypoint.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
run_cmd="dotnet run --server.urls http://*:80"    
until dotnet ef database update; do
>&2 echo "SQL Server is starting up"
sleep 1
done    
>&2 echo "SQL Server is up - executing command"
exec $run_cmd
```

**StackTrace:**

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 474
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Data.MySqlClient/MySqlConnection.cs:line 741
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Data.MySqlClient/MySqlConnection.cs:line 396
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySql.Data.MySqlClient/MySqlConnection.cs:line 362
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
```

Comment: Are both containers exist in the same network? Do you have a `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

For 2 containers to talk to each other, we would have to create a bridge/overlay network and use that network for running containers. Below are the steps

1. Create a Bridge-Network

   ```
   docker network create -d bridge my-bridge-network
   ```
2. Run MySQL Container by connecting to the bridge network

   ```
   docker run --name mysql --network my-bridge-network -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=SomePassword -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:latest
   ```
3. Update AppSettings.json to use `mysql`(Container name of MySQL Server) instead of `localhost` as server

   ```
   "ConnectionStrings": {
        "InstaTranscribeDBConnection": "server=mysql;port=3306;database=wordpress;user=root;password=SomePassword;"
   },
   ```
4. Create a new docker image for .NET core app and run the docker container by connecting to the bridge network

Alternatively, **Docker Compose** can also be used for managing multiple containers and their networks. Please check the below link for reference https://github.com/mahedee/articles/blob/master/microservices/Dockerize_Both_MySQL_And_ASP_NET_Core_Web_App_In_Windows_Container.md